# Egypt tourist visa denied without any supportive document

Tags: air-travel, indian-citizens, visa-refusals, tourist-visas, egypt

The title may be misleading. But what I meant is that when I (Indian passport holder) recently applied for an Egyptian tourist visa in Israel, they collected only the following:

1. 4 copies of the passport identification page
2. 4 copies of my Israeli student visa/residence permit
3. 4 passport-size photographs

Even though I had all other necessary documents (flight tickets both to and from Egypt, night accommodations, bank account statement, credit card statement, my Israeli university certificate, detailed itinerary, cover letter, filled application form, health insurance, etc), they refused to take any of those and returned my passport to me asking me to call them a week later inquiring about the approval.

Upon inquiry today, I was told the application has been rejected and was not given any reason. One problem I see is that my Israeli visa is not valid when I leave Egypt, and the consular officer might think I may stay in Egypt illegally. But, the purpose of providing a confirmed flight ticket out of Cairo to India and a bank account statement from an Indian bank was to show my intention to go out of Egypt but I did not have opportunity to submit that.

I was told to wait for 3 weeks at least before applying again and don't know if they will accept documents that support my intention to leave Egypt. What else can be the reason behind the rejection and what is the best option I have currently? Also, how can I increase my chance in second application?

Any answers will be highly appreciated.

P.S. I have a US visa and Schengen visas from several EU countries and have always left the country before expiration. But they did not have any idea about it since they did not collect a passport from me.

Comment: I am completely confused about your question. You are an Indian, but want to travel to Egypt to get home while visiting Israel? 1. Where are you now? 2. Where did you apply for what Visa?